# Appearance API ignoring dynamically created controls in Monotouch

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios

I'm not sure if this is a monotouch, cocoatouch issue or if I'm doing it wrong.

I have this code in my AppDelegate

```
UILabel.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
```

And it works on most labels except the ones I create by

```
va label = new UILabel();
```

has anyone seen this too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use new UILabel (someRectangle) as the constructor to create your UILabel.